# Rails asset pipeline javascript_include_tag jquery doesn't work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I pulled my "require jquery" line out of my main application.js (because I have a need for it to be loaded in the HEAD section) and so in the HEAD section of my layout I have this line:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
```

In development environment that works fine and creates this HTML:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
```

Which works (however I noticed there is *no* jquery file in the assets/javascripts directory, strange)

However in production this link gets generated as:

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

Which does NOT work. I noticed most of the javascript gets minified and the names get mangled (probably for caching purposes) in production. But since this file never existed in the javascript folder to begin with I'm guessing that's the problem. Is it because this library was added through a rails gem?

Answer (score 0):

`<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>`, this worked because you have added `jquery.js` to your `assets/javascripts` path. Then in development mode, any file inside assets folder can be accessed.

You can view the included assets by inspecting `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` in the Rails console.

In `Production` environment, all assets needs to be compiled and are written to the location specified in `config.assets.prefix`. By default, this is the `public/assets` directory. And those we have specified in the manifest files will only be precompiled. So, I think for production, you need to include it in the manifest file, `application.js` by default (`//= require jquery`) to be precompiled and to be available for serving in production.

To know more about asset pipeline, please refer [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @asolberg: Hey, did you get it running in production?